# how to get the ids of the row after using to_frame()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

after using to_frame(), how do I get the id of the row.

For example:
After to_frame()

|  | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 35 |
| 2 | 34 |

If this is the table, is there a way to get the id 1 or 2

Edit:
What I am trying to do is I got all the unique product/Item in the data and stored the data into another table named stock.
I then checked how many of the products were sold, so I used `value_count.to_frame()` to store the value_counts as its own column. However, when I run this code, the stock name becomes the id, which is not what I wanted. I wanted the stock name and the values to count on a separate column in the same table. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @AliTou how should I edit this?

Comment: `df.index[0]`try this.

Comment: To calculate the total number of items by product name, use the following method. `df.groupby('name').sum()`

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you so much! I got it to work by using your first comment